# Changing structure of form data to suit required json POST in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a post request called from a form which accepts user input from the fields, but the post request expects a particular format for the data and has sections which are nested as the below:

```
{
  "Product": {
    "name": "App1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "location": "C:\app1"
  },
  "Owner": {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "email": "john@smith.com"
  },
  "Clients": [
    {
      "name": "client1",
      "location": {"address": "123 Jon street", "contact_number": "123456789"}
    },
    {
      "name": "client2",
      "location": {"address": "123 Jon street", "contact_number": "123456789"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything above except for the client list is to come from user input in the form.
My app.js is below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import clients from './components/clients';
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = data => {
       axios
        .post('/api/product',
            data,
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}
         )
        .then(response => {console.log(response.data)})
        .catch(error => {console.log(error.data)});
    };


  //const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Client listing</h3>
      <clients />
      <h3>Owner Details</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Owner name: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Owner name" {...register("Ownernane", { required: "Invalid Entry", maxLength: 80 }) } /><p>{errors.Ownernane?.message}</p>
        <label>EMail: </label><input type="text" placeholder="Email" {...register("Email", { required: "Invalid Entry", pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i }) } /><p>{errors.Email?.message}</p>
        
        <h3>Product details</h3>
        <label>Name: </label><input type="text" placeholder="name" {...register("name", { required: "Invalid Entry", maxLength: 80 }) } /><p>{errors.name?.message}</p>
        <label>Location: </label><input type="text" placeholder="location" {...register("location", { required: "Invalid Entry", maxLength: 100 }) } /><p>{errors.location?.message}</p>
        <label>Version: </label><input type="text" placeholder="version" {...register("version", { required: "Invalid Entry", maxLength: 12 }) } /><p>{errors.version?.message}</p>
        

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to do this?, Im not sure if its the terminology im using but Im having alot of trouble finding instructions for this and guess its a pretty common thing to deal with. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to change the structure of data, You can define an array of fields or nested fields by `react-hook-form` easily, here is an example:

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <label>Owner name: </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Owner name"
    {...register('Owner.name', { required: 'Invalid Entry', maxLength: 80 })}
  />
  <p>{errors.Owner?.name?.message}</p>
  <label>EMail: </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Email"
    {...register('Owner.email', {
      required: 'Invalid Entry',
      pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i,
    })}
  />
  <p>{errors.Owner?.email?.message}</p>

  <h3>Product details</h3>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="name"
    {...register('Clients.0.name', { required: 'Invalid Entry', maxLength: 80 })}
  />
  <p>{errors.Clients?.[0]?.name?.message}</p>
  <label>Location: </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="location"
    {...register('Clients.0.location', { required: 'Invalid Entry', maxLength: 100 })}
  />
  <p>{errors.Clients?.[0]?.location?.message}</p>
  
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

with above structure, the data which sends to onSubmit will have below structure:

```
{
  "Owner":{"name":"value","email":"value"},
  "Clients":[{"name":"value","location":"value"}]
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much, this is so much easier then what i was trying to do!

Would you be able to help with also adding more fields to the data before sending off the post request? such as Owner.DateSubmitted and similar?

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sorry to add on! but is there a way to add additional fields to the json data prior to sending the post request? possibly in the onSubmit function? I made an edit above but not sure if its been seen. Very much appreciate any help. thanks again

Comment: You mean, you want to add field dynamically or you want just add values to the form value before send it to server?

Comment: Id like to add data dynamically, to the json data being sent in POST body. Is this possible?  Its currently only the data in my form.

Im unsure where this should be done, I was thinking in the onSubmit function but not sure if this is the ideal location or if its even doable there

Comment: in the `onSubmit` you can do whatever you want with `data`, adding anoter value, removing some values, eiditing them and etc. form example:
`const onSubmit = data => {
       axios
        .post('/api/product',
            {...data, extraInfo: { name:'aa' } },
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}
         )
        .then(response => {console.log(response.data)})
        .catch(error => {console.log(error.data)});
    };`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240557/discussion-between-saeed-shamloo-and-kelly-b).